# Non-GPL JSON-RPC library for C++

Tags: c++, json-rpc

What non-GPL libraries are available for writing JSON-RPC servers and clients in native C++?

According to http://json-rpc.org/wiki/implementations, there seems to only exist one implementation of JSON-RPC for C++, namely [JsonRpc-Cpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsonrpc-cpp), but that only available under GPL. Unfortunately we cannot use GPL code in our software.

The [JSON RPC C Library](http://www.big-llc.com/software.jsp) from big-llc.com, could be an alternative. They call it "a free lightweight implementation C library to handle JSON-RPC requests easier", but they do not mention the licensing.

Anyone who knows of other options?

Comment: JSON RPC C Library: looking at the code shows LGPL as their license

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JsonRpc-Cpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsonrpc-cpp/) is available as LGPLv3 since version 0.3 release 2011-05-06.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly know nothing about this, but came across it whilst searching for other serialization tools:

[JSON-RPC and XML-RPC in C/C++](http://realtimelogic.com/ba/doc/en/C/WebServices.html)

Comment: Yeah, they seem to have moved the page. Fixed, for now.